# How to get distinct count on sub table joined via two different way

Tags: postgresql, join, query, count, distinct

I have 3 below tables in my db

```
CREATE TABLE main_table
(
id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE middle_table
(
id            SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name          VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
main_table_id INT,
CONSTRAINT fk_main_table FOREIGN KEY (main_table_id)
    REFERENCES main_table (id)
);

CREATE TABLE sub_table
(
id              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name            VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
main_table_id   INT,
middle_table_id INT,
CONSTRAINT fk_main_table FOREIGN KEY (main_table_id)
    REFERENCES main_table (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_middle_table FOREIGN KEY (middle_table_id)
    REFERENCES middle_table (id)
);
```

I have also inserted a sample data for convenience

```
INSERT INTO main_table (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Main 1');

INSERT INTO main_table (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Main 2');

INSERT INTO middle_table (id, name, main_table_id) VALUES (1, 'Middle 1', 1);

INSERT INTO sub_table (id, name, main_table_id, middle_table_id) VALUES (1, 'Sub 1', 1, 1);

INSERT INTO sub_table (id, name, main_table_id) VALUES (2, 'Sub 2', 2);

INSERT INTO sub_table (id, name, main_table_id) VALUES (3, 'Sub 3', 1);
```

and below is the query which I am running

```
SELECT mt.id,
    mt.name,
    count(DISTINCT st.id)             AS direct_st_count,
    count(DISTINCT mt_st.id)          AS via_middle_st_count
    --  count(DISTINCT mt_st.id OR st.id) AS st_count
    --  Please note I need distinct count of sub tables whether they are joined directly or via middle table
FROM main_table AS mt
    LEFT JOIN sub_table st ON mt.id = st.main_table_id
    LEFT JOIN middle_table ON mt.id = middle_table.main_table_id
    LEFT JOIN sub_table mt_st ON middle_table.id = mt_st.middle_table_id
GROUP BY mt.id;
```

I am unable to get distinct count of sub table(it can be joined directly or via middle table).

Comment: Your scheme is wrong. The row in `sub_table` may easily refer to one row in `main_table` directly, and on another row - via `middle_table`.

Comment: you are right. its a legacy system and I am not allowed to change schemas @Akina

Comment: If so then you MUST to decide what link of these two contradictable ones will be ignored.

Comment: doesnt matter really but lets say if there is a duplicate sub table joined id for one main table we consider the one joined via middle table

Comment: @Akina how can I tell count function to apply distinct on these two joined tables and ignore duplicate(AS st table) if found

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```sql
SELECT mt.id main_id, mt.name main_name, st.id sub_id, st.name sub_name  
FROM main_table AS mt
LEFT JOIN sub_table st ON mt.id = st.main_table_id
WHERE st.middle_table_id IS NULL
-- AND st.main_table_id IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT mt.id, mt.name, st.id, st.name
FROM main_table AS mt
LEFT JOIN middle_table ON mt.id = middle_table.main_table_id
LEFT JOIN sub_table st ON middle_table.id = st.middle_table_id
WHERE st.middle_table_id IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY main_name, sub_name
```

First subquery selects the rows joined directly and have no indirect joinings. Second selects indirect joinings.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d9b4ef0b443b3ad3a6b5c8584612705f)

If you do not need in rows from main table which have no matched rows from sub table at all then uncomment the condition.